# Getting the error: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. Working in dev site. Not working in PROD site

Tags: asp.net, excel, oledb

I have an ASP.NET web application hosted in a standalone server.
- Windows server 2012 R2 x64

Installed the package from this below url:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255

We are getting error while trying to reading from an uploaded excel file in PROD site hosted as subdomain.
https://admin.domainname.com/readexcel.aspx
The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

But it is working in DEV site setup as subdomain. 
https://admindev.domainname.com/readexcel.aspx

When trying to include admin section in the domainname.com site. The functionality works.
https://www.domainname.com/Admin/readexcel.aspx

- MS Office is not installed in the machine.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error when I wanted to run an Access application without having it installed. I fixed it by installing this components:
https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=13255

If you need both versions (32 & 64bit) then install one version in a regualar way and the 2nd one by using the command line with the `quite` parameter (otherwise it will complain):

```
.\AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe /quiet
```

Hope this helps!